# Drop empty Impala partitions

Tags: impala

Impala external table partitions still show up in stats with row count 0 after deleting the data in HDFS and altering (like `ALTER TABLE table RECOVER PARTITIONS`) refreshing (`REFRESH table`) and invalidation of metadata.

Trying to drop partitions one by one works, but there are tens of partitions which should be removed and it would be quite tedious.

Dropping and recreating the table would also be an option but that way all the statistics would be dropped together with the table.

Is there any kind of other options in impala to get this done?

Comment: If you know which partitions do drop, you can do so with a single DDL statement `ALTER TABLE foobar DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (partitionkey = 'foo' OR partitionkey = 'bar' OR ...);`

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelSchaefers, 
The problem was that there were tens of partitions so it wouldn't be the most convenient way but definitely you solution could work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround through HIVE.

By issuing `MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename SYNC PARTITIONS` then refreshing the table in impala, the empty partitions disappear.